# How to use angular.js variable inside the script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am displaying some elements on a view using angular.js and trying to connect these dom elements using jquery connections.The elements are getting displayed properly but I am not able to use them inside the sscript tag.

```
<div ng-repeat = "impact in activity.text" style=" margin-right: auto;background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                                      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
                                      min-width: 4em;
                                      min-height: 3em;
                                      max-width: 29ex;
                                      margin: 1.2em;
                                      padding: 0.6em;

                                      word-wrap: break-word;
                                    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
                                    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                                    border-radius: 16px;
box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);"  class="impact\{{$index}}" id="">

    \{{impact}}</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('div.impact\{{$index}}').connections({ from: 'div.actors' }).length;
        var connections = $('connection, inner');
        setInterval(function() { connections.connections('update') }, 10);
    });

</script>


</div>
```

Here I am generating unique class name for every element. But I get the error in console when I use the same value in script tag.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.impact{{$index}}
```

[image]

Comment: You just don't do that in angularjs. You need to create a directive and put any DOM manipulation/external plugins code in there

Comment: If you try using AngularJS and jQuery together like that, you're gonna have a bad time. Choose one over the other.

Comment: That jquery needs to be in a directive. There is no `$index` where you have the code and angular won't interpolate inside a script tag

Comment: @gicheetham the library I am using is jQueryConnections and I cannot find an alternate for that in angular.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your logic, $index represents the current ng-repeat's iteration index, which doesn't exist outside of the loop itself, for obvious reasons.

Do you want to run this JS code for each generated DIV?
You could move the script tag inside the loop, but Angular doesn't parse script tags, as mentioned by charlietfl.

You could write a directive and attach it to the ng-repeat DIV as an attribute:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('updateConnections', function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.connections({ from: 'div.actors' }).length;
            var connections = angular.element('connection, inner');
            $interval(function() { connections.connections('update') }, 10);
        }
    };
});
```

To use the directive:

```
<div update-connections ng-repeat="impact in activity.text">...</div>
```

Comment: How angular elements are getting passed to the directive? Should I place this directive inside the controller?

Comment: In this case, the "element" variable represents the div that it was added to. Add this directive in its own file and load it in your main html file. Make sure you replace "myApp" with the actual name of your angular app.

Comment: I did the same and I can see it gets me the same result I was getting earlier. My element is having objects with key ,value pair. I want all the values to be connected to a single key. I tried to change the code with  element.connections({ from:element.id  }).length; But it is not working.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on in your code, I suggest you put "debugger;" (without quotes) at the end of the directive and check the variable values in the browser's debugger to find the problem.

Comment: i tried to debug and this is what I am getting [Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object

id:"d323232"
text: 
0:"dmkkjsdfjksd"
1:"dmkkjsdfjksd"    Answer you have written is completely fine but I am stuck if I have to connect these above texts to their id how do I replace that instead of div.actors

Comment: I have added a picture which can give you actual idea. If I use div.actors, it connects all the elements to the first actor.

Comment: Thanks a lot @timeNomad . I figured it out.